# rfm69 on M0 Express... init() doesn't work

Tags: c++, wireless, feather

I have already connected succesfully the rfm69 on my Feather M0 Express... but I cannot do it again.

The connections are (in the order of the rfm69):

```
Vin -> 3V
Gnd -> Gnd
En  -> (nothing)
G0  -> 9
SCK -> SCK
MISO -> MI
MOSI -> MO
CS  -> 10
RST -> 6
```

The code of the setup is

```cpp
#include <SPI.h>
#include <RH_RF69.h>

#define RFM69_CS      10
#define RFM69_INT     9
#define RFM69_RST     6
#define LED           13

// Singleton instance of the radio driver
RH_RF69 rf69(RFM69_CS, RFM69_INT);

void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);

  Serial.println("Feather RFM69 RX Test!");
  Serial.println();

  // manual reset
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, HIGH);
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);
  delay(10);

  if (!rf69.init())                  
    //***********************************
    Serial.println("init failed"); 
  else
    Serial.println("init ok"); 
  
  // Defaults after init are 434.0MHz, modulation GFSK_Rb250Fd250, +13dbM (for low power module)
  // No encryption
  if (!rf69.setFrequency(434.0))
    Serial.println("setFrequency failed");
  else
    Serial.println("setFrequency ok"); 

  // If you are using a high power RF69 eg RFM69HW, you *must* set a Tx power with the
  // ishighpowermodule flag set like this:
  //rf69.setTxPower(14, true);

  // The encryption key has to be the same as the one in the client
  uint8_t key[] = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08,
                    0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08};
  rf69.setEncryptionKey(key);
  
#if 0
  // For compat with RFM69 Struct_send
  rf69.setModemConfig(RH_RF69::GFSK_Rb250Fd250);
  rf69.setPreambleLength(3);
  uint8_t syncwords[] = { 0x2d, 0x64 };
  rf69.setSyncWords(syncwords, sizeof(syncwords));
  rf69.setEncryptionKey((uint8_t*)"thisIsEncryptKey");
#endif
  Serial.println("Fin du Setup"); 
}
```

But during the execution, the program stops at `//**************************`
I do not understand.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot and merry Xmas

Comment: To be clear, you are seeing `"init failed"` printing and then no further output on the Serial Monitor, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

The "init failed" do not appear. Everything stops at "//******".
I have compared to another RFM69 program.
I have added a line " digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);" at the begining of the "//manual reset" and it works now.
the sequence
digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);
digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, HIGH);
delay(10);
digitalWrite(RFM69_RST, LOW);
seems to be more efficient.
... it remains a few mysteriuos for me.

Thank you

Comment: You should be able to mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean... it seems thus I am not able to do it. I almost never use forums.